# Error when building websocket-driver when installing rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation

I have the following error when trying to install rails with `gem install rails`

```
C:\Windows\system32>gem install rails
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/websocket-driver-0.7.1/ext/websocket-driver
C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/ruby.exe -I C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20200126-10756-4x6n18.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/websocket-driver-0.7.1/ext/websocket-driver
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/websocket-driver-0.7.1/ext/websocket-driver
make "DESTDIR="
generating websocket_mask-x64-mingw32.def
compiling websocket_mask.c
make: *** [Makefile:244 : websocket_mask.o] Erreur 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/websocket-driver-0.7.1 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.6.0/websocket-driver-0.7.1/gem_make.out
```

I'm running on windows 7 x64 and I installed `Ruby+Devkit 2.6.5-1 (x64)` from https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/

I did install the devkit that comes in with the installer and updated the system. I spent a few hours trying to figure out what was going on and reading about similar errors other had (usually with more explicit messages or compil errors on the .c file), I'm running out of ideas.